# Unity 3D: Player specific information

Tags: unity-game-engine

I'm very new to Unity so sorry for stupid question.

What are the best practices to store player-specific data for multiplayer games?
Say players share the same map but "know" different parts of it.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! You might find [programmers.SE](http://programmers.stackexchange.com) a better fit for this question, as it is broad and conceptual, rather than about concrete code. See http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254570/choosing-between-stack-overflow-and-programmers-stack-exchange

Comment: 'Best Practice' questions are not [well recieved](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/search?q=best+practice) at programmers.se.